# python collision detection?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

So I've been working on a python game for a project.I'm having the trouble now that If I put an obstacle in the game I can't make it respond to my picture like when my picture collides with it, the game ends. I've been at it for quite sometime now but I'm unable to figure out the code.Any help will be greatly appreciated.I seriously need help with this.Please not that I'm a beginner and I just started studying python a month ago.So please try to understand. I've attached the code below.

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
BACKGROUNDCOLOR = (181, 230, 29)
FPS = 30
pixels = 5


pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((990, 557))
pygame.display.set_caption('Clumsy Claire :D')

background = pygame.image.load('grass.jpg')
backgroundRect = background.get_rect()
size = (990, 557)
background.get_size()

image = pygame.image.load('snail 2.png')
imageRect = image.get_rect()

stone1 = pygame.image.load('rock.PNG')
stone1Rect = stone1.get_rect()
stone2 = pygame.image.load('rock.PNG')
stone2Rect = stone2.get_rect()


BROWN =  (128,64,0)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (98, 555), (98,69), 12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (98, 16), (98,1), 12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (94, 3), (283, 3),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (278, 457), (278, 3),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (278, 554), (278, 512),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (274, 554), (470, 554),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (465, 554), (465, 90),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (465, 35), (465, 0),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (465, 3), (657, 3),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (652,555 ), (652, 502),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (652, 449), (652, 0),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (648, 553), (844, 553),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (838, 553 ), (838, 138),12)
pygame.draw.line(background, BROWN, (838, 84 ), (838, 0),12)

while True:
    imageRect.topleft = (10,488)
    moveLeft = False
    moveRight = False
    moveUp = False
    moveDown = False

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                   moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                   moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_UP:
                   moveUp = True
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                   moveDown = True

           if event.type == KEYUP:
               if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    moveLeft = False
               if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    moveRight = False
               if event.key == K_UP:
                    moveUp = False
               if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    moveDown = False

          if moveLeft and imageRect.left > 0:
              imageRect.move_ip(-1 * pixels, 0)
          if moveRight and imageRect.right < 990:
              imageRect.move_ip(pixels, 0)
          if moveUp and imageRect.top > 0:
              imageRect.move_ip(0, -1 * pixels)
          if moveDown and imageRect.bottom < 557:
              imageRect.move_ip(0, pixels)

          windowSurface.blit(background, backgroundRect)
          windowSurface.blit(image, imageRect)
          rock1 = background.blit(stone1,(658,337))
          rock2 = background.blit(stone2,(225,150))


          pygame.display.update()

          mainClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: There is currently no attempt to make anything collide. Have you looked into e.g. [`colliderect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) at all?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `colliderect` function to your code among other things.  Right now you have no way to test collisions.  Paste this below your blit code:

```
if imageRect.colliderect(stone1Rect):
    print('Game Over')
    pygame.quit()
if imageRect.colliderect(stone2Rect):
    print('Game Over')
    pygame.quit()
```

This code here:

```
rock1 = background.blit(stone1,(658,337))
rock2 = background.blit(stone2,(225,150))
```

also needs to be changed to this:

```
windowSurface.blit(stone1, (658, 337))
windowSurface.blit(stone2, (225, 150))
```

The reason we need to change the above is this:  your code is blitting on your background image instead of the window; which is a bad practice.

For some reason, I'm guessing you're learning python from inventwithpython.org ;D  That's the way I learned it too (if my guess is right ;D)

If you need any more help or have questions just comment below.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes! you guessed it right.I'm learning from inventwithpython.org and it has barely been two weeks and now we're supposed to make a game out of it :/ & Well yea I've been messing around with this colliderect function alot too but still what happens is that the snail just goes under it.I can't seem to figure that out:(

Comment: So you're saying the code I gave doesn't work?  I can look at it again when I get home.

Comment: Yea its not working e.g. I want to quit the game if the player hits the rock but its not doing so instead its just moving through the rock.& Yea it'll be great if you can help me with it.I have my project submission after one day and I just don't know what to do anymore:(